# Mysql table Pivot to compare sales from current and previous year from the same table

Tags: mysql, join, html-table, phpmyadmin, pivot-table

I have created mysqltable with sales data from different years.[link to sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce3aa/4)

I want to have an  column in the table where it shows  sales from ThisYear and one extra column with total sum of sales from Lastyear, as shown in figure.

```
CREATE TABLE agreement (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    supplier VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      sales VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      yearDate DATE NOT NULL,
  yearx VARCHAR(10)


);

INSERT INTO agreement
    (Id, supplier, sales, yeardate,yearx)
VALUES
    ('1', 'AB Foods', '2', '2020-01-01', '2020'),
    ('2', 'BC Foods', '2', '2020-01-01','2020'),
    ('11', 'AB Foods', '34', '2020-02-01', '2020'),
    ('22', 'BC Foods', '80', '2020-02-01','2020'),
    ('5', 'AB Foods', '5', '2021-01-03','2021'),
    ('6', 'BC Foods', '5', '2021-01-03','2021'),
     ('52', 'AB Foods', '51', '2021-02-03','2021'),
    ('16', 'BC Foods', '50', '2021-02-03','2021')
    
;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce3aa/4)

[image]

My approach to solve problem:

```
    SELECT
 supplier,
 yearx,
 sum(if(month(yearDate) = 1, sales, 0))  AS Jan,
 sum(if(month(yearDate) = 2, sales, 0))  AS Feb,
 sum(sales)  AS Total_ThisYear,
  sum(sales)  AS Total_LaastYear
FROM agreement
GROUP BY supplier, yearx
order by yearx
```

but seems I need a where clause inside the case statement.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: @Strawberry it is included in the link already mentioned above http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce3aa/4

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot do this without a join. This might be working solution:

```
SELECT
 a.supplier,
 a.yearx,
 
 sum(if(month(a.yearDate) = 1, a.sales, 0))  AS Jan,
 sum(if(month(a.yearDate) = 2, a.sales, 0))  AS Feb,
 sum(a.sales)  AS Total_ThisYear,
 IFNULL(ls.sales, 0)  AS Total_LaastYear

FROM agreement a

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT b.supplier, YEAR(b.yearDate) AS 'year', SUM(sales) AS 'sales' FROM agreement b
  GROUP BY b.supplier, YEAR(b.yearDate)
) ls ON ls.supplier = a.supplier AND ls.year = yearx - 1

GROUP BY a.supplier, a.yearx

order by a.yearx
```

Comment: thank you really appreciate your help. It works. I was wondering in order to compare sales with last year for the months less than current month. For example ThisYearSales VS LastyearSale (untill current month which is 2) . Is this the right way to go: ls.month <= month(CURRDATE())

Comment: Yes - if you execute the subquery only, than you see list of sales for each supplier and year - and than is connected desired year (-1). But the condition with month must be inside subquery so WHERE MONTH(b.yearDate) <= MONTH(NOW(()). Most important is, that result connected by join with ON condition must be only one row - otherwise the sums in main select wont work correctly.

Comment: the SUM(sales) as 'sales' looks like this now  sum(
          case when YEAR(month) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND Month(month) <= Month(CURDATE())
               then amount 
               else 0 end